# Google Sheets -fill a cell with contents of a different cell when not blank

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to Google Sheets. I and am trying to make a spreadsheet where column A has a list of words and when I type an x or something in a cell in a different column (lets say column B)it automatically fills with the word contained in column A in the same row.  I have tried to use =IF(CELL(not(empty... with different arguments but I really don't know what I am doing.  I'm trying to read up on Google Apps Script and figure out a way to write a macro to accomplish this but again, I'm not sure if I need a macro.  I would appreciate any help I can get on this.

Answer (score 2):

The answer above is also correct, alternatively you can use the following formula:

### if(B1 <> "",B1, "")

Enter the above formula into cell A1 and drag it down column A as far as it needs to be.
Broken down this says, if B1 is not blank, then make A1 the same as B1, else make A1 blank.

Comment: Thank you. The explanation you gave helps.  I used  =IF(B1<>"", A1,"") so that if B1 is not blank is should say what A1 says otherwise it should stay blank.  The problem I have now with that is that B1 immediately says what A1 says even though it was blank before I put the function in.  If I delete the word from B1 the function goes away too.

Comment: Hmm I might be understanding this incorrectly. You can maybe share a public sheet so I can have a look what's going on. The function should not be deleted in A1 if you delete the value in B1. It should just enter a blank value. Feel free to send me a personal message with link to your sheet if you want to go down that way.

Comment: I ended up getting some more help and got it to do what I want with a script.  I still have a problem that I don't know how to solve.  With this script when you type anything into a cell, the cell will take on the value found in that row in column A.  Now I need to delete what is in the cell but simply deleting the cell contents doesn't work.  I'm assuming I need a script for this as well but I'm not sure what it would be.  Any thoughts?  Here's the link to the spreadsheet.   
 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14FlQkj51EEG9XT5VKvUQtgAam2z8KuNr1GvR4hyupeQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi, assuming you must be using the on edit trigger in your script. (When something in the spreadsheet is changed, run the following script.) Still not to sure what you are trying to achieve here, even after looking at the spreadsheet. I am assuming if I were to type any characters or words into cell B2 that word would change to "Red", yes? And so if I then delete the word "Red" from cell B2, it "does not work", could you elaborate on what you mean when you say it does not work.

Comment: Yes you are right in what I am trying to do and I used the on edit trigger.  When I say the delete doesn't work I mean when I type something into B2 and it says "Red," if I select the word "Red" and try to delete it, the word "Red" will not go away.

Comment: Hi, as I understand the word red will not go away due to your trigger. When you delete a value in cell B2, you are editing your document. Causing your on edit trigger to take effect. In other words, when you delete the value in B2, the script kicks off again and puts the value "red" back in B2. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. Is there any way you can think of to get the words to be deleted?  Or a different way of getting the cells to fill with the words from column A when they are edited without using the on edit trigger?

Comment: @woos213 See the original answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Google Script unnecessary.

Just use [Formula](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/46977?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en). Here you can put to A1:

```
=B1
```

and in A1 will be the same word as in B1. If you need condition, try to A1 set:

```
="My magic word is: " & IF(ISBLANK(B1),"(nothing)",B1)
```

Comment: I tried what you said but it doesn't give me the result I'm looking for.  I only want B1 to say the same word that is in A1 if someone puts a check mark or an x or some other character in B1.  Otherwise I want B1 to stay blank.

Comment: So basically I want cell B1 to say IF I am empty, leave me empty.  If I am not empty, fill me with the word in A1.